# Get set of Unique records from a query without using distinct

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like

```
SELECT E1.name,E1.id from E1
union all
SELECT E2.name,E2.id from E2
```

Both E1 and E2 has more than one record for given unique combination of name and id (say the same person has two different phone numbers so E1.phone is different for two rows with same E1.name and E1.id). Hence, a number of duplicate records in the output of my query

I want a Unique set of rows from the above query.I know I can use a '`DISTINCT`' clause on top of the query like:

```
SELECT distinct name,id 
from 
(SELECT E1.name,E1.id from E1
union all
SELECT E2.name,E2.id from E2);
```

But as far as I know, Distinct has a performance overhead.
Is there any other way to achieve a set of unique records that is more efficient?
Right now, I cant think of any, except using

`row_number() over partition by (name, id order by name)`

But is using `row_number()` more efficient than `DISTINCT`?
Is there any other way I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a UNION (not UNION ALL), there will be an implicit DISTINCT, so there is no need to make an explicit DINSTINCT

Comment: I am sorry,the query has union all not union. have updated my question.

Comment: Ok, so use UNION instead of UNION ALL. I don't believe there is a more efficient way. You can try to GROUP BY all columns, it has the same effect, but I doubt that it is more efficient than DISTINCT.

Answer (score 1):

To explain further, 
`ANALYTIC` is used for `AGGREGATION`, and `DISTINCT` is used to get what it means. DISTINCT + ANALYTIC => Meaningless and bad query.

In your case, as already suggested, all you need to do is, use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`. UNION ALL includes the duplicates, while UNION will remove them. So no need to use `DISTINCT` explicitly, let Oracle do it's job for you.

Comment: UNION internally does a implicit DISTINCT on all the records fetched, doesn't it?

Comment: It picks distinct rows from result set of rows returned by each query.